# ? at the end of a capture group

Tags: ruby, regex

I understand that a question mark at the beginning of a capture group (?:pattern) indicates that this pattern should not create a backreference, but what does it mean in the following example where the question mark is at the end of the capture group after the wildcard?

```
  self =~ /(.*?)_(\d+)$/
```

Code

```
class String
# used to instantiate a model based on a dom_id style
# identifier like "person_10"
  def to_model
    self =~ /(.*?)_(\d+)$/
    class_name, id = $1, $2
    class_name.classify.constantize.find(id)
  end
end
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/13401514/10396

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is non-greedy expansion.  [A trailing `?` converts `*` and `+` from greedy to non-greedy](http://doc.infosnel.nl/ruby_regular_expressions.html).  A non-greedy wildcard will select the smallest matching set of characters, not the largest possible.   See [this blog](http://robertpyke.blogspot.com/2009/02/ruby-regex-non-greedy-operator-using_05.html) for an explanation

Comment: Also it means that whether it's inside a capture group or not (just to be clear)

Comment: Actually it means that whenever it stands after a quantifier like `*` and `+`.